# Perl match abba pattern

Tags: regex, perl

I have a subroutine in a Perl script that should return `true` if the string passed to it contains any 4 characters that match the pattern of an outer pair around an inner pair 'abba', 'baab', 'acca', and so on. It should not match 'aaaa'. I do not understand why the regex is not working. I would expect that the following should print 'found', but it does not.

```
print 'found' if 'abba' =~ /(.)q(?!\g1)(.)\g2\g1/;
```

What is wrong with my regex?

Comment: You know, you really shouldn't look for regex golf answers on SO. That's kinda cheating :P

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz It's not for regex golf, but it is an answer I probably shouldn't look up :). See the google results for Advent of Code.

Comment: You can also write your pattern like that: `(.)\1*+(.)\2\1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a stray `q` in your pattern.

```
$ perl -le'print "found" if "abba" =~ /(.)(?!\g1)(.)\g2\g1/;'
found
```